# Vite prevents nodemon from watching

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I am working on a vite-typescript-express-ssr-react project inside docker.
(I am mounting the root directory to the docker container)

I use vite hmr which is working fine for frontend development but when I start the project with nodemon for backend development nodemon doesn't restart the server

I am using the dev:server script to start for backend development.

```
"dev:server": "npx nodemon",
"dev:client": "npm run build:client && vite --config vite.config.ts dev --host 0.0.0.0",
"build:client": "vite build --outDir dist/client --ssrManifest",
```

here is my nodemon.json

```
{
  "watch": ["src", "server.ts"],
  "ext": "ts,tsx",
  "exec": "tsx server.ts"
}
```

when starting with dev:server I see this in the console but its not restarting on save:

```
app  | > app@1.0.0 dev:server
app  | > npx nodemon
app  | 
app  | 
app  | [nodemon] 3.0.2
app  | [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
app  | [nodemon] watching path(s): src/**/* server.ts
app  | [nodemon] watching extensions: ts,tsx
app  | [nodemon] starting `tsx server.ts`
```

my project filestructure looks like this:

```
project-root/
|-- src/
|   |-- client/
|   |   |-- context/
|   |   |-- hooks/
|   |   |-- pages/
|   |   |-- router/
|   |   |-- ...
|   |
|   |-- server/
|   |   |-- config/
|   |   |-- controller/
|   |   |-- models/
|   |   |-- api/
|   |   |-- ...
|   |
|   |-- public/
|
|-- vite.config.ts
|-- tsconfig.json
|-- package.json
|-- server.ts
|-- nodemon.json
|-- Dockerfile
|-- docker-compose.yml
|-- ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it's always the same, once I decide to ask on stackoverflow I figure it out right-away.

I added the following code to my nodemon.json file

```
"legacyWatch": true,
```

Should have red the [docs](https://github.com/remy/nodemon?tab=readme-ov-file#application-isnt-restarting) before posting, sorry for the noise...

> **Application isn't restarting**
> In some networked environments (such as a container
> running nodemon reading across    a mounted drive), you
> will need to use the `legacyWatch: true` which enables    Chokidar's
> polling.
>
> Via the CLI, use either `--legacy-watch` or `-L` for short:
>
> `nodemon -L`
>
> Though this should be a last resort as it will poll
> every file it can find.